# Terraform/HCL - for_each iteration over map of maps to set unique first level map name

Tags: foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, hcl

I'm attempting to reduce the amount of code required in main.tf for an EKS Blueprint module for defining "Teams". My understanding is that it's a map of map data structure but I was not able to find an example for setting the nested map's name value using for_each.

Example Repo: https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints/tree/main/modules/aws-eks-teams#input_application_teams

```
  # EKS Application Teams

  application_teams = {
    # First Team
    team-blue = {
      "labels" = {
        "appName"     = "example",
        "projectName" = "example",
        "environment" = "example",
        "domain"      = "example",
        "uuid"        = "example",
      }
      "quota" = {
        "requests.cpu"    = "1000m",
        "requests.memory" = "4Gi",
        "limits.cpu"      = "2000m",
        "limits.memory"   = "8Gi",
        "pods"            = "10",
        "secrets"         = "10",
        "services"        = "10"
      }
      manifests_dir = "./manifests"
      # Belows are examples of IAM users and roles
      users = [
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/blue-team-user",
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/blue-team-sso-iam-role"
      ]
    }

    # Second Team
    team-red = {
      "labels" = {
        "appName"     = "example2",
        "projectName" = "example2",
      }
      "quota" = {
        "requests.cpu"    = "2000m",
        "requests.memory" = "8Gi",
        "limits.cpu"      = "4000m",
        "limits.memory"   = "16Gi",
        "pods"            = "20",
        "secrets"         = "20",
        "services"        = "20"
      }
      manifests_dir = "./manifests2"
      users = [

        "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/other-sso-iam-role"
      ]
    }
  }
```

With this example, we have a bunch of teams defined in our main.tf.

Since our team values are the same, I am trying to find a way to iterate over the "team-blue" and "team-red" values.

variables.tf

```
variable "teams" {
  type = list(string)
}
```

my_vars.tf

```
teams = [
  "team-red",
  "team-blue",
  "team-green",
  "team-orange"
]
```

I'm not sure if using a list of strings for team names is a valid way to pass data into each team's name field or if I should be constructing a map variable instead. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution by using local values since terraform doesn't seem to support nested variables.

Added something like this to my main.tf

```
locals {
  teams = { for t in var.teams :
    t => {
      "labels" = {
        "appName"     = "example",
        "projectName" = "example",
        "environment" = "example",
        "domain"      = "example",
        "uuid"        = "example",
      }
      "quota" = {
        "requests.cpu"    = "1000m",
        "requests.memory" = "4Gi",
        "limits.cpu"      = "2000m",
        "limits.memory"   = "8Gi",
        "pods"            = "10",
        "secrets"         = "10",
        "services"        = "10"
      }
      manifests_dir = "./manifests"

      users = [
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/blue-team-user",
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/blue-team-sso-iam-role"
      ]
    }
}
```

Then set my original `application_teams` config as follows

```
application_teams = local.teams
```